# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function' and an issue with list comprehension

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function to calculate Simpson's rule that takes a function as an argument.

```
# Imports
from numpy import sum, exp, linspace

def compSimpsons(a, b, n, f):
  endpts = linspace(a, b, n+1) # Use linspace to get endpoints
  functions = []
  f = lambda x : f
  fvals = [f(x) for x in endpts]
  h = (b-a)/n
  h4 = h**4
  h5 = h**5
  sum_even = sum(fvals[2:(n-1):2])
  sum_odd = sum(fvals[1: :2])
  Sn = (h/3)*(fvals[0] + fvals[-1] + 2*sum_even + 4*sum_odd)
  result_actual = 1.5 - 0.5 * exp(-2)
  print("%5g | %.16f | %.16f | %.16f | %.16f" % (n, h4, h5, Sn, abs(Sn - result_actual)))
```

However, I get the following error when I try to run the program:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-123-44442d95a7b4> in <module>
      3 
      4 for n in range(2, 41, 2):
----> 5   Sn = compSimpsons(0, 1, n, (1+exp(-2*x)))

<ipython-input-122-b9245c03d75c> in compSimpsons(a, b, n, f)
     12   sum_even = sum(fvals[2:(n-1):2])
     13   sum_odd = sum(fvals[1: :2])
---> 14   Sn = (h/3)*(fvals[0] + fvals[-1] + 2*sum_even + 4*sum_odd)
     15   result_actual = 1.5 - 0.5 * exp(-2)
     16   print("%5g | %.16f | %.16f | %.16f | %.16f" % (n, h4, h5, Sn, abs(Sn - result_actual)))

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'function' and 'function'
```

I modified the function to print fvals and got the following:

```
[<function compSimpsons.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f39576e5170>, <function compSimpsons.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f39576e5170>, <function compSimpsons.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7f39576e5170>]
```

It seems that I'm creating a list of functions when I want a list of values, but I'm not sure how to fix this problem. What can I do?

Comment: `f = lambda x: f`, your lambda function always returns itself.

Comment: You are not calling your function with a function as the last parameter.